# TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'

Tags: flask

layout.html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <label id="headLabel"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="sidePanel">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <label id="footerLabel">Created By: Anish Saha</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html :-

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
(% block content %}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Error:** 
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'.

Kindly help, I'm new to using flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in

```
(% block content %}
```

change `(` to `{`:

```
{% block content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

for

> {% block content %}   #remember there is a space between *block content*

however regarding on your error

> {% endblock %}  #no *content* behind #no space in between